# Sanity auto caching data with nextjs 13 app router

Tags: caching, next.js13, sanity

It doesn't matter even if I update the data of my sanity backend as it's loading the caches again and again. I have to clear the browser cache and hard reload the website manually which is pretty annoying.

[image]
I dint do any type of extra configuration to enable this caching. I somehow came to know that the useCdn property inside of the createClient is occuring this so I've tried both true and false with it

A:

```
export const client = createClient({
  projectId,
  dataset,
  apiVersion,
  useCdn: true,
});
```

B:

```
export const client = createClient({
  projectId,
  dataset,
  apiVersion,
  useCdn: false,
});
```

but everything went in vain.
Is there some possibilities that this caching is occuring because of some version mismatch?
the following are the nextjs and next-sanity versions:

> "next": "13.4.7",
> "next-sanity": "^5.5.11",

I've tried testing it after deployment also but the data doesn't update automatically until I clear the browser cache and do a hard reload.